# PHP Cookie Checking Not Working Inside Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to check if this cookie exists, but it just doesn't work when executed inside Bootstrap's Navbar here. This Navbar is saved separately as a **navbar.php** file and loaded in other pages using a php include when required.

I have tried copying the following cookie check code to a separate **cookie.php** file it worked with the correct output.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE["login"]))        
{
echo "COOKIE TRUE"; 
}
else
{
echo "COOKIE FALSE";    
}      
?>
```

So according to my understanding something is interfering with the cookie check inside that navbar. Also I have checked this cookie through Chrome browser inspect option and it's perfectly there. It's a fresh cookie and not expiring anytime soon. Here is the full **navbar.php** code.

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://example.com">
<img src="http://example.com/static/logo.png" width="75" height="75" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
</a>
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE["login"]))        
{
echo "COOKIE TRUE"; 
}
else
{
echo "COOKIE FALSE";    
}      
?>
</nav>
```

I have expected the page to show COOKIE TRUE but instead it was always COOKIE FALSE inside that Bootstrap's Navbar.

Since you need to know where I set this cookie, here is the code in my **login.php** page. The included **database.php** has the database location specified and this code works and cookie is getting created everytime I request it to do so.

**UPDATE**: Thanks @TheMouseMaster for pointing out the mistakes in the login code. I use SQLite3 database for this php login and I have made some changes.

```
<?php
include 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\database.php';

if(isset($_POST['btnlogin']))
{
if ($db)
{
$login = $db->query('select email, password from users');
while ($row = $login->fetchArray())
{
$email=$row['email'];
$password=$row['password'];
if ($email==$_POST["txtemail"]&&$password==$_POST["txtpassword"])
{
setcookie("login", "true", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
header("location: http://example.com");
}
else
{
header("location: http://example.com/register");
}
}
}
$db->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: We need to see where you set the cookie

Comment: @Andreas I have added information about where I set this cookie.

Comment: If I am reading your php code sample correctly, you are reading through your entire "users" database table, and OVERWRITING your $email and $password variables with each DB row.  THEN AND ONLY THEN do you check if what is in $email and $password match your login attempt.  Which means that your cookie is only going to get set properly if the username and password you are trying to match is the very last one in your users table

Comment: @TheMouseMaster Thanks for pointing that out. I have made some changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the way I have included the **navbar.php** in each page. Instead of loading it from a URL like;

```
<?php include 'http://example.com/navbar.php';?>
```

I have replace it with;

```
<?php include 'navbar.php';?>
```

or

```
<?php include '../navbar.php';?>
```

for pages within sub-directories to properly pick it up. Now it works!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where and how are you setting the cookie? Do you set the 4th parameter?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

For example:

setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time); Only for the current URL path

The better option: setcookie("cookiename","cookievalue", $time,"/"); For all pages/folders on that domain,

Comment: I have added information about where I set this cookie.